# VBA Object Required Error when my variables are error, dont know how to fix

Tags: vba, excel

I am looping through named range to check if any of the cells are errors, and if yes, highlight them. The condition is dependent on two columns, and when both are errors (#NA) then the code doesnt work. How can I fix?

It gives an error when sCharacter and sCheck are

```
For i = 10 To 16

    sCharacter = ws_Sheet1.Range("A" & i)
    sCheck = ws_Sheet2.Range("B" & i)

    If IsError(sCharacter) And IsError(sCheck) Then
        ws_Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ws_Sheet1.Range("E" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

    Else
    End If

    If IsError(sCharacter) And sCheck = "Y" Then
        ws_Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ws_Sheet1.Range("E" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Else
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: This code seems like it wouldn't compile - missing `End If`

Comment: This is what the code looks like, i just updated. Even then error error throws an error, i want it to continue loooping, highlight if both are errors.

Comment: Instead of using IsError() checks, trying matching for "#NA" strings instead? I find that to be more reliable sometimes

Comment: @adam bad advice IMO, assuming we're talking about actual cell error values, whose variant subtype will be `Variant/Error`. An `Error` value can't be compared to a `String` literal (or anything for that matter) without throwing run-time error 13 "type mismatch" - that's pretty much exactly why VBA has an `IsError` function ;-)  If you have sheet formulas returning "NA" strings, replace that literal with `NA()` function calls; the cell will then return an error that Excel and VBA understand as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retyping the variables used to check for errors to variant will allow you to use the `IsError()` function to check for errors.  Using `Cstr()` to cast the variables into strings will allow you to test for a string value without throwing a `Error 13 Type mismatch` error.

[image: Error Code Demo]

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim vCharacter As Variant, vCheck As Variant
    Dim ws_Sheet1 As Worksheet, ws_Sheet2 As Worksheet
    Set ws_Sheet1 = Sheet1
    Set ws_Sheet2 = Sheet2

    For i = 10 To 16
        vCharacter = ws_Sheet1.Range("A" & i)
        vCheck = ws_Sheet2.Range("B" & i)

        If IsError(vCharacter) And (IsError(vCheck) Or CStr(vCheck) = "Y") Then
            ws_Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Resize(1, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this? (slightly revised from your original code, including changing `sCharacter` and `sCheck` to `rCharacter` and `rCheck` and declaring them each as `Range`).

```
Sub Test()
    Dim l As Long
    Dim ws_Sheet1 As Worksheet, ws_Sheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim rCharacter As Range, rCheck As Range

    Set ws_Sheet1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws_Sheet2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    For l = 10 To 16

        Set rCharacter = ws_Sheet1.Range("A" & l)
        Set rCheck = ws_Sheet2.Range("B" & l)

        If IsError(rCharacter) And IsError(rCheck) Then
            ws_Sheet1.Range("D" & l & ":E" & l).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End If

        If IsError(rCharacter) And rCheck.Text = "Y" Then
            ws_Sheet1.Range("D" & l & ":E" & l).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End If

    Next l
End Sub
```

Comment: This could work too. I tried the one below changing it to Variant instead and it worked. Thanks